# Increase 1A to 5A

Tags: power-supply, power

I want to increase 1A to 5A with 12V. 
I have a 12V 1A transformer. 
I want to produce 12V 3A or 5A from it. 
If it is possible than tell me how can I do this?
Please give me the circuit diagram.

Comment: That is not possible for the whole time, the transformer only supply 12 VA. Do you need this 5A only for a short period of time? If so, then you can store energy in a capacitor or battery which is loading during the idle time.

Comment: next week : perpetual motion...

Comment: magic wand to get 5x more than its power rating

Comment: @SolarMike See Tom's comment for an example of why your suggestion is incomplete.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon and your comment for tony's answer? Or did you miss it?

Comment: Solution: use five of these transformers. Load-balancing them still needs to be done, though.

Comment: @JohnDvorak - You think the there is enough knowledge base with the OP to be able to even begin to safely deploy your solution? And how do we even know what "transformer" is in the way the OP may be using it. Could even be 12VDC switching type wall warts for all we know.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I don't, actually. I was just pointing out the impossibility of his requirements as they are.

Comment: Surely if you use a MOSFET with a transconductance of 5 amps per volt the requirement will be met quite simply? No comments please LOL.

Comment: Shahbaz - IF you want to get the extra current for short periods -
 say 1 second or less, then there are ways of doing it. If you want continuous output at higher current then it is not possible BECAUSE  you are trying to get more energy OUT than you are putting in. 12V x 1A = 12 Watts. 12V x 3A = 36 Watts. You cannot continuously get 3 times as much energy out as you are inputting.

Comment: @SolarMike I saw Tony's comment and considered cutting and pasting my comment to him as well. I did not do so for reasons which overall seemed 'good enough'. You are very welcome to email me and I'll comment further. Based on your SE-name and  profile we probably have some overlap in areas of interest which would outweigh me honouring you for sole comment :-). | Some of my (solar) "Orange Children" : http://bit.ly/SL2MINIAFRICA.  [Scroll up/down - don't click].

Answer (score 3):

> If it is possible than tell me how can I do this?

**It's not.**  Go get a 12 V 5 A power supply.

The very low level knowledge of physics and electronics exhibited by your question indicates that trying to explain this would be pointless or exceed a reasonable length here.  We expect those that ask here to have at least a high school level understanding of physics.

Again, go get a 12 V, 5 A power supply.

Comment: +1 :-). ie useful, not actually rude per se, expands RTFM into potentially useful advice ... :-).

Answer (score 1):

I'll give an answer that fits with the level of knowledge from which you ask this question.

**No** this is not possible.

You will have to exchange your transformer for a different one that can produce the output that you want.

Another thing that might be suggested is to get some more of the transformers that you already have but there are a whole lot more things that you have to know about before you could even begin to deploy them together in a safe manner.

Comment: +5 (If I could) - It's nice to see someone trying to help a newcomer , rather than acting like childish [smart alecks](https://wiki2.org/en/Smart_aleck).